# Delphi XE - Access https SVN server under proxy

Tags: delphi, svn, proxy, tortoisesvn, delphi-xe

I have a SVN Server over internet and I want to access it from my work where there's a proxy. With TortoiseSVN I just configure the Proxy Settings. 
Can I Configure Proxy for Delphi XE SVN Plugin ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Version Insight with a SVN server over a proxy you have to do this:

- open the file %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers in a text editor
  (for Win 7 this should be c:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers)
- look there for the section "global"
- add there the following names, fill in your values for them and save the file

  - http-proxy-host
  - http-proxy-port
  - http-proxy-username
  - http-proxy-password
  - http-proxy-exceptions

At the end it should look like this

```
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
http-proxy-host = defaultproxy.whatever.com
http-proxy-port = 7000
http-proxy-username = defaultusername
http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
```

Entering the proxy information into TSVN might work too, but I have never tested this.

Comment: Thanks Uwe, it works !
FYI: WinXP path to files is C:\Documents and Settings\YouruserName\Application Data\Subversion

Answer (score 1):

All svn clients (at least all client using the official svn library) use the same settings files. So if you've set the proxy for TSVN, you've automatically set them for your plugin as well.

Comment: using Win7 x64 / TSVN 1.7.7 x64 - that is not the case. Global SVN settings not touched at all while TSVN reaches out via proxy. So it has to have some local way to store and pass those parameters